# How to implement a generic method that returns a specific type on an interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am developing several WCF Http Web Services. All of those WCF web services have the same operations, but every WCF Web Service, for a given operation, returns a different type.

For example, there are two services `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, both with the operation `GetData`. However, for  `ServiceA` the `GetData` operation must return an `int` and for `ServiceB` the `GetData` operation must return a `string`:

### ServiceA Interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceA
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetData();
}
```

### ServiceA Implementation:

```cs
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public int GetData()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### ServiceB Interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceB
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();
}
```

### ServiceA Implementation:

```cs
public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "any text";
    }
}
```

The WCF web services need to expose the metadata correctly, I mean, they must expose the data types (`int`,`string`) that the `GetData` operation returns in order to tell the service consumer which type of data expect. In other words, having the XSD schemas.

As you know, when you create a new WCF Web Service, VS creates an interface for declaring the operations and declare the required `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` attributes, and creates the class that implements the interface.

In order to standarize the code and save a little time typing the implementation of the interfaces, I want to create an interface, common to all WCF Web services, that declares the common operations (e.g. `GetData`) as generic and then, specify the type on implementation.

I wanted to do something like this:

### Common Interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceCommon
{
    [OperationContract]
    T GetData<T>();
}
```

### ServiceA Interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceA : IServiceCommon
{

}
```

### ServiceA Implementation:

```cs
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public int GetData()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, I was getting the following error:

> 'ServiceA' does not implement interface member 'IServiceCommon.GetData()'

How can I implement any service class that returns any type of value on GetData method?

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing the post, I came up with the solution by declaring the interfaces as follow:

### Common Interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceCommon<T>
{
    [OperationContract]
    T GetData();
}
```

### ServiceA Interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceA : IServiceCommon<int>
{

}
```

### ServiceA Implementation:

```cs
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public int GetData()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```